CollectionView's RemainingItemsThresholdReached event firing before loading the data on UI
I have a collectionview on my UI and I load 20 items initially. I have added RemainingItemsThresholdReached event for loading next 20 items when I reach the end of first 20 items. But after loading first 20 it is instantly load the next 20 and again load the next 20 and repeated up to load all the items.
I have added the same kind of logic on a different page and on there it is working fine. So I suspect the issue is with the layout used on that page. Below I have added the layout structure I am using.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:rgAnimations="clr-namespace:RGPopup.Maui.Animations;assembly=RGPopup.Maui" 
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:RGPopup.Maui.Pages;assembly=RGPopup.Maui"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
    xmlns:maps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui/maps"
    xmlns:sensors="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Essentials"
    xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Maui;assembly=FFImageLoading.Maui"
    xmlns:fftransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Maui"
    BackgroundColor="White">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local2:ProfileNameConverter x:Key="nameConverter"></local2:ProfileNameConverter>
            <local3:DatetimeToStringConverter x:Key="cnvDateTimeConverter"></local3:DatetimeToStringConverter>
            <local3:TweetUrlsLinkconverter x:Key="urlJoinConverter"></local3:TweetUrlsLinkconverter>
            <local3:SpecialCharactorConverter x:Key="specialCharactorConverter"></local3:SpecialCharactorConverter>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="#eeeeee">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="{OnIdiom Phone=60, Tablet=90, Desktop=60}" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    //Header layout
                
            </Grid>

            <ScrollView 
                x:Name="frienddetails_scrollview"
                IsVisible="False"
                Orientation="Vertical" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                
                <StackLayout
                    Margin="15">
                    
                    //Middle layout

                    <CollectionView 
                        x:Name="historyCollectionView"
                        SelectionMode="None"
                        RemainingItemsThreshold="1"
                        RemainingItemsThresholdReached="LoadMoreHistory"
                        BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout
                                    Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                    <StackLayout
                                        x:Name="Day_layout"
                                        Orientation="Vertical"
                                        BackgroundColor="#eeeeee"
                                        Padding="5">
                                        
                                        <Label
                                            Text="{Binding userLocationTO.createdTime,Converter={StaticResource cnvDateTimeConverter}}"
                                            TextColor="#313131"
                                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                                            <Label.FontSize>
                                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>18</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>27</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>18</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                                </OnIdiom>
                                            </Label.FontSize>
                                        </Label>
                                    </StackLayout>

                                    <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                                            <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />-->
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <StackLayout
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <StackLayout
                                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                                <Image 
                                                    Source="{Binding IconType}"
                                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                                    <Image.WidthRequest>
                                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>20</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>30</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>20</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                                        </OnIdiom>
                                                    </Image.WidthRequest>
                                                    <Image.HeightRequest>
                                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>20</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>30</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>20</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                                        </OnIdiom>
                                                    </Image.HeightRequest>
                                                </Image>

                                                <Label 
                                                    x:Name="Emergency_label"
                                                    Text="{Binding triggerType}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                    TextColor="#1c98d7">
                                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>16</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>24</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>16</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                                        </OnIdiom>
                                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                                </Label>
                                            </StackLayout>


                                            <Grid>
                                                <Label 
                                                    Text="{Binding AllAudits}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                    Margin="0,2,0,8"
                                                    TextColor="#545454">
                                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>14</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>21</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>14</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                                        </OnIdiom>
                                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                                </Label>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>

                    <Label
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsVisible="False"
                        Text="No history found!"
                        x:Name="no_history_label">
                        <Label.FontFamily>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Roboto-Light" />
                                <On Platform="Android" Value="Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto-Light" />
                                <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto" />
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </Label.FontFamily>
                        <Label.FontSize>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>18</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>26</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>18</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </Label.FontSize>
                    </Label>

                    <StackLayout x:Name="chat_stack" IsVisible="{Binding chatVisibility}" VerticalOptions="Fill" >
                        <StackLayout.HeightRequest>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>600</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>900</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>600</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </StackLayout.HeightRequest>

                        <RefreshView  
                            IsVisible="{Binding chatVisibility}"
                            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                            Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">

                            <CollectionView 
                                x:Name="MyTweetsList" 
                                Margin="0,5,0,5"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                RemainingItemsThreshold="0"
                                IsVisible="{Binding chatVisibility}"
                                RemainingItemsThresholdReached="LoadMoreTweets"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackLayout
                                            x:Name="Item"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                            Orientation="Vertical">

                                            
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <CollectionView.HeightRequest>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>400</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>600</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>400</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </CollectionView.HeightRequest>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </RefreshView>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <Label
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        IsVisible="{Binding ComingSoonVisibility}"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Text="No Messages Yet."
                        x:Name="no_announcement_label">
                        <Label.FontFamily>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Roboto-Light" />
                                <On Platform="Android" Value="Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto-Light" />
                                <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf#Roboto" />
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </Label.FontFamily>
                        <Label.FontSize>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>18</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>26</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>18</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </Label.FontSize>
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            
            <Grid 
                x:Name="tweetBox"
                IsVisible="False"
                Margin="0,0,0,10">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                //message sending layout
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

I have issue with the historyCollectionView and have another CollectionView on the same page.
Can anyone tell what is the issue by checking the above xaml layout codes?
Updates:
xaml.cs codes
public partial class FriendDetailsPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<UserLocationHistoryHBList> allHistoryList;
    bool loadMoreHistory = false;
    bool haveHistoryItemsToLoad = false;
    
    public FriendDetailsPage(UserFriendHBList friendsdetails)
    {
        allHistoryList = new ObservableCollection<UserLocationHistoryHBList>();
        await Task.Run(async () => await SetHistoryListItems(monitorId));
    }
    
    public async Task SetHistoryListItems(string selecteduserId)
    {
        try
        {
            //API Call
            if (locationHistory.userLocationHistoryHBList != null)
            {
                if (locationHistory.userLocationHistoryHBList.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in locationHistory.userLocationHistoryHBList)
                    {
                        //list iteration and adding list to collection
                        allHistoryList.Add(item);
                    }
                    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        //setting data to collectionview
                        historylistview.ItemsSource = allHistoryList;
                        UserDialogs.Instance.HideHud();
                    });
                    if (locationHistory.userLocationHistoryHBList.Count == 20)
                    {
                        haveHistoryItemsToLoad = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        haveHistoryItemsToLoad = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    SetNoHistoryAlert();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SetNoHistoryAlert();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.HideHud();
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>" + ex);
        }
    }

    //Load more items API call
    void LoadMoreHistory(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (haveHistoryItemsToLoad)
        {
            haveHistoryItemsToLoad = false;
            loadMoreHistory = true;
            SetHistoryListItems(friendsdata.userId);
        }
    }
}

Update:
I have created a demo with dummy data and uploaded here.
In this demo it will load the first 10 items and before showing it on the UI, it will load the next 10. The next 10 should load when reaching the end of first list, that is the issue.

You can fix this by explicitly setting a height for the CollectionView, or by placing it in a parent container that restricts its size, like a Frame or BoxView. This will ensure the RemainingItemsThresholdReached event only triggers when the user scrolls near the bottom of the currently visible items.
Solution: Constrain the Height of the CollectionView
Method 1: Explicit HeightRequest
You can set an explicit height for the CollectionView, ensuring it doesn’t expand indefinitely.
<!-- Setting an explicit HeightRequest -->
<CollectionView 
    x:Name="historylistview"
    SelectionMode="None"
    RemainingItemsThreshold="1"
    RemainingItemsThresholdReached="LoadMoreHistory"
    BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
    HeightRequest="300"> <!-- Adjust this height based on your layout -->
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout
                Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <!-- Your existing template code -->
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

Method 2: Constrain Using Parent Container (e.g., Frame)
Wrap the CollectionView in a Frame or BoxView with a constrained height:
<!-- Wrapping the CollectionView in a Frame with a set height -->
<Frame 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    HeightRequest="300" <!-- Adjust height as necessary -->
    BorderColor="Transparent"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <CollectionView 
        x:Name="historylistview"
        SelectionMode="None"
        RemainingItemsThreshold="1"
        RemainingItemsThresholdReached="LoadMoreHistory"
        BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout
                    Margin="0,0,0,10">
                    <!-- Your existing template code -->
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</Frame>


Explicit HeightRequest: Setting an explicit height ensures that the CollectionView does not expand to fit all its items, thus preventing the RemainingItemsThresholdReached event from firing too early.

Using a Parent Container with Set Height: Wrapping the CollectionView in a Frame with a defined HeightRequest ensures it occupies only the specified space, enabling incremental loading as expected.



======Updated=======
Here's my answer,tested and proven to work.
Don't attempt to load data incrementally in a CollectionView that's in a StackLayout. This scenario will cause an infinite loop to occur where the CollectionView will keep expanding.
I've moved the CollectionView, which has a name attribute as historylistview,
to the outermost part. Grid layout with two rows, wrapping stacklayout and collectionview (problematic control)
        <Grid  RowDefinitions="auto,*">


            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
             ...
            </StackLayout>


            <CollectionView  BindingContext="{viewmodel:HistoryViewModel}" Grid.Row="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding allHistoryListAttribute}"            
             
                    HeightRequest="200"
x:Name="historylistview"
SelectionMode="None"
RemainingItemsThreshold="1"
RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}"
...        
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </Grid>


Note that here I'm using the remainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand, and here I'm creating a new view model. Bind the collection control with the name attribute of historylistview to the HistoryViewModel, and the core data loading function is below.
Annotating the Loard Morestori Method and the Setistoli Tims Method under the Friedtiger page. The functionality of these two codes I moved to the HistoryViewModel view model file.Don't  change the ItemSource of CollectionView control.
Here's the code in my HistoryViewModel view model file.
internal class HistoryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    static bool haveHistoryItemsToLoad = false;
    int i = 1;
    public ObservableCollection<UserLocationHistoryHBList> allHistoryList = new ObservableCollection<UserLocationHistoryHBList> {

   new UserLocationHistoryHBList{ AllAudits = "monster", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = " monster type 1" },
    new UserLocationHistoryHBList{ AllAudits = "monster", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = " monster type 1" },
      new UserLocationHistoryHBList{ AllAudits = "monster", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = " monster type 1" },
        new UserLocationHistoryHBList{ AllAudits = "monster", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = " monster type 1" },
          new UserLocationHistoryHBList{ AllAudits = "monster", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = " monster type 1" },
            new UserLocationHistoryHBList{ AllAudits = "monster", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = " monster type 1" },

};
    public ObservableCollection<UserLocationHistoryHBList> allHistoryListAttribute {


        set {
            allHistoryList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(allHistoryListAttribute));
        }
     get => allHistoryList; }

    public async Task LoadMoreHistory()
    {
            SetHistoryListItems("933");
    }
    public HistoryViewModel() {

        allHistoryList = new ObservableCollection<UserLocationHistoryHBList>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            UserLocationHistoryHBList locationHistory = new UserLocationHistoryHBList { AllAudits = i+"monster", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = " monster type 1" };

            allHistoryListAttribute.Add(locationHistory);
        }
       
        LoadMoreCommand = new Command(async => LoadMoreHistory());
    }
    public ICommand LoadMoreCommand { set; get; }
    public async Task SetHistoryListItems(string selecteduserId)
    {
       
        if (haveHistoryItemsToLoad) return;
        try
        {

        //Prioritizes the current load state to prevent other asynchronous operations from executing， haveHistoryItemsToLoad is a static parameter.
            haveHistoryItemsToLoad = true;

        //A two-second delay prevents frequent command triggering
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            allHistoryListAttribute.Add(new UserLocationHistoryHBList() { AllAudits = "Audit 21", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = "type 1" });
            allHistoryListAttribute.Add(new UserLocationHistoryHBList() { AllAudits = "Audit 22", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = "type 1" });
            allHistoryListAttribute.Add(new UserLocationHistoryHBList() { AllAudits = "Audit 23", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = "type 1" });
            allHistoryListAttribute.Add(new UserLocationHistoryHBList() { AllAudits = "Audit 24", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = "type 1" });
            allHistoryListAttribute.Add(new UserLocationHistoryHBList() { AllAudits = "Audit 25", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = "type 1" });
            allHistoryListAttribute.Add(new UserLocationHistoryHBList() { AllAudits = "Audit 26", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = "type 1" });
            allHistoryListAttribute.Add(new UserLocationHistoryHBList() { AllAudits = "Audit 27", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = "type 1" });
            allHistoryListAttribute.Add(new UserLocationHistoryHBList() { AllAudits = "Audit 28", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = "type 1" });
            allHistoryListAttribute.Add(new UserLocationHistoryHBList() { AllAudits = "Audit 29", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = "type 1" });
            allHistoryListAttribute.Add(new UserLocationHistoryHBList() { AllAudits = "Audit 30", date = "13/08/2024", triggerType = "type 1" });
            haveHistoryItemsToLoad = false;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           
        }
    }
}

I reproduce your problem. You are right, it's really the XAML file layout that causes the problem.
Here is my solution.
In your code,remove the outer ScrollView tag that surrounds the CollectionView with the name property set to 'historyCollectionView'.
Warning! ScrollView objects should not be nested. In addition,ScrollView objects should not be nested with other controls that provide scrolling, such as
CollectionView , ListView , and WebView.
For more information about ScrollView and CollectionView, please refer to
ScrollView and
Load data incrementally.

I tried removing the frienddetails_scrollview, but I am facing the same issue. In addition, I can't scroll the collectionview items when removing the scrollview.

After updating the answer mention here about the update as a comment by mentioning me, else I will not notice that.

I have already tried the updated suggestion and that is also not working. The UI is completely blank when adding grid instead of stack.

@MatthewPans I have updated the answer ,Please give it a try.

@SreejithSree  I have updated the answer ,Please give it a try.

@can you share the working demo?

Here's a link to my code.@MatthewPans

I tried updating the StackLayout with a Grid like the below screenshot. But still facing the same issue. (The underlined one is the incremental CollectionView. https://i.sstatic.net/AJUtYye8.png

Let me the try the sample you shared.

I downloaded the project but I can't run it on my system, I am getting some errors, please check the screenshot. https://i.sstatic.net/T4aVstJj.png

You can try to clean your solution and rebuild it . Besides , can you tell me your version of .net and the platform you are using ? @MatthewPans

I am using .net 8 and on Android platform I am facing this issue.

I have a good solution, the only files involved in the code change in the case are the HistoryViewModel, FriendDetailsPage.xaml.cs and FriendDetailsPage.xaml files, you just need to add these codes to your original working case, and you can run it with a little debugging.@MatthewPans

I found a simple solution instead of rewriting the entire logic and added it as an answer. Thank you very much for your support.
